Uniform convergence and Lebesgue integral (Bogachev 10.4)
I was reading chapter 10.4 of Bogachev's Measure Theory book, when this definition is given:

And, after this definition, he does the following observation:

My issues are: what does he mean when he says "by mean of uniform approximations"? And, more precisely, what is he effectively doing? It seems to me that he's somehow bringing the limit inside of the integral (in the sense that, since $f$ is bounded, there exists a sequence of simple functions $(f_n)_n$ that converges uniformly to $f$, and he's bringing the limit for $n\rightarrow +\infty$ inside the integral), but why can he do it? Why can we put the limit inside the integral for all the integrals involved (with respect to $\mu, |\mu|$ and $\mu^{\mathcal{B}}(\cdot,x)$)?
I thought about some sort of application of the dominated convergence theorem, which explains also the $|\mu|$-integrability of the function $x \mapsto \|\mu^{\mathcal{B}}(\cdot, x)\|$, since this hypothesis gives the finiteness of the measure $\mu^{\mathcal{B}}(\cdot,x)$ for $|\mu|$-almost every $x$, but is not clear to me how to precisely use this fact.
Just to make it clear: if $\mu$ is a measure on a space $X$, then $\|\mu\|:=|\mu|(X)$, where $|\mu|$ is the total variation of $\mu$.

@Masacroso how is this related to the integral equality that we want to obtain?
